# Static spacetime and Schwarzschild solution

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, definition, vector-fields

The Schwarzschild spacetime $(\cal{M},g)$, for which the metric is a solution for the Einstein field equation in vacuum,
$$g=-\Big(1-\frac{2m}{r}\Big)dt^2+\Big(1-\frac{2m}{r}\Big)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2$$
is surely stationary in region $\{r>2m\}$ and I have read that is also static.

By definition a [spacetime is static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spacetime) if there exists a function $t:\cal{M}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t if $X$ is a killing vector field, then $X^b=g(X,X)dt$, where $X^b$ is the one form associated to $X$ through the metric $g$.

> Now what I have not understood the sense of this definition and so I can't understand how looking at the metric above I can say that this is static. I mean why $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ satisfies the condition for the staticness?

Answer (score 1):

All you talk about in the question has very much to do with the *Lie derivative*. You can look up the definition online, but in its basic sense it is another way to measure change (this should be obvious from the word **derivative**). The Lie derivative, as opposed to other derivatives, measures a change in the field under a diffeomorphism.

I like to think about it like this: imagine you are walking on a mountain, and you ask yourself how much your position will change if you keep walking forward. So what you do is walk a certain distance (should be infinitesimal but forget this right now) in a certain direction and then you take a look back, maybe you look down, maybe up, depending on where you stood. You can now compare the two positions, and so measure some type of change in your position right?

Well, now imagine you are a tensor and you move infinitesimally along a path $\gamma(\lambda)$ with tangent vectors $X$ (it is a field), and then you **pullback** yourself to where you started. Then congratulations, you have Lie differentiated yourself.

A Killing vector (Unfortunate flashy name in my opinion, but just named after Wilhelm Killing. You can think that it "kills" the tensor in the derivative, as it turns to zero.) is just a vector field $X$ which is tangent to some curve, along which the Lie derivative is zero (the tensor doesn't change). For the case of the metric, the coordinate expression is

$
\mathscr{L}_X g_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu X_\nu + \nabla_\nu X_\mu = 0
$

You can check with this that the metric is in fact static. But really I hope that, after the answer, you don't need the formula to feel why the metric is static: after wandering some distance in a path *purely* in the time direction the Schwarzschild metric doesn't change in any way.

Comment: In the formula above remember that $X_\mu dx^\mu$ is COVARIANT, while $X^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ is CONTRAVARIANT although both are the same vectors. Just remember to turn $X^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ to its covariant form, and then you can use the formula.

Answer (score 0):

consider Killing's equation for schwarzschild:

$$\nabla_{(a}v_{b)} = 0$$

consider the ansatz $v_{b} = a(r)dt$

Then,

This gives us one nontrival equation (t,r):

$$\begin{align}
0 &= \partial_{r}a - \Gamma_{rt}{}^{t}a\\
&= \partial_{r}a - a\frac{M/r^{2}}{1-2M/r} \\
ln(a) &= ln(C) + (1/2)ln\left(1-2M/r^{2}\right)\\
a &= C\left(\sqrt{1-2M/r}\right)
\end{align}$$

So, $dt$ is not the covariant form of the killing vector, it has to be scaled by a factor of $\sqrt{|g_{tt}|}$

Comment: It is a killing vector field since the metric does not depends explicitly on $t$!! And also $\partial \phi$ is killing!

Comment: You're mistaken in the comments above (the answer is correct): if the metric is independent of $t$ then the *contravariant* KVF $\xi^a= (1,0,0,0)$. The correct *components* of the *covariant* KVF are as Jerry wrote above. You'll often see people writing that the KVF is $\partial_t$ but this really means the same thing.

Comment: @Umaxo when working with Killing vectors it's pretty standard to work with both raised and lower indices components. I don't think the last statement from Jerry Schirmer that $\xi = \partial_t$ is not a Killing vector is correct. But his expression for the covariant components one finds from Killing's equation is.

Comment: @Umaxo Ah if you're only gripe was with the last statement than I don't disagree with you, I misunderstood to mean the answer itself was incorrect. Seems like a notational issue.

Comment: @Eletie fair enough. I did not check his equations, only the last sentence.

Comment: @Umaxo corrected

Comment: And yeah, the version of this that uses explicit lie derivatives of the metric, rather than the form using covariant derivatives, you end up with $\xi^{a}\partial_{a}g_{bc}$ terms, instead of Christoffel symbols, and it's still equivalent

Comment: @JerrySchirmer from your answer I don'understand how recognize the staticness of schwarschild solution...